# Can't run Hello World on my Android device

Tags: android

What's with the downvote? I know this is a dumb question but is it not a "good" question?

I've never done any Android programming but thought it might be fun to put together a toy app for my morning and evening commutes.

So I'm going through [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) tutorial.

When I go through the steps to "run on real device" (connect via USB and enable USB debugging) and then click run, I get the following:

[image: target unkown]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats your device os version ?

Comment: great question. could you tell me how to look it up and I'll post?

Comment: are you installed device driver in your system

Comment: Go to Setting -> About Phone -> Android Version

Comment: what operating system you use for developing ?

Comment: see on top of image you attached "Select a device compatible with target Android 4.1" it cause problem and you use 2.2.3 so set your application target to 2.2.3 or below you will able to run your application on your device

Comment: which device you are connecting to the system ?

Answer (score 5):

This is how I solved that in my Ubuntu:

http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html

Save this file at /tmp/ as android.rules

> ```
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666"
> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666"
> ```

Run the following commands:

> ```
> $ sudo cp /tmp/android.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
> $ sudo chmod 644   /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
> $ sudo chown root. /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
> $ sudo service udev restart
> $ sudo killall adb
> ```

Disconnect the USB cable between the phone and the computer.
     Reconnect the phone.
     Run adb devices to confirm that now it has permission to access the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a linux machine, you have to restart your ADB.

That's the problem you are facing I think.

To restart ADb follow the below steps,

1)Login as root user.

2)Go to the Directory where you have android-sdk folder.

3)Then traverse to platfrom-tools  directory.

4) Then execute the below commands,

> ./adb kill-server
>
> ./adb start-server

Now you will be able to see a message like this,

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

If not repeat the fourth step once again.

Answer (score 1):

set your application target to `android 2.2.3` then run because you set your application target to  4.1 but your device is compatible with only 2.2.3 or lower version of android and restart your device.

Comment: how/where do I set my application target?

Comment: right click on projet in eclipse select properties>select Android>and set project build target to 2.2.3 or lower click apply and ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your device vendor id, as described at Android Developers : [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

Answer (score 0):

Plug into USB and from the command line run:

```
$ lsusb
```

This will give you the ID of your device (and other connected USB devices). For example, if you have a Samsung Galaxy S II Skyrocket connected you would get:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04e8:685e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (USB Debugging mode)
```

In this case the Vendor ID is “04e8″ and the Product ID is “685e″.

Then edit:

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Add the following line to it and save it:

```
SUBSYSTEMS==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”04e8″, ATTRS{idProduct}==”685e″, MODE=”0666″
```

Restart udev:

```
$ sudo restart udev
```

Check if the device is recognized:

```
$ adb devices
```

Sometimes I also have to restart adb:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

Answer (score -1):

i think USB debugging is not enabled in your android device.

Set it in your device go to

> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging
>
> USB debugging = True