# Unable to run android app in asus nexus

Tags: android, ubuntu, device, adb

I am trying to run my android app from eclipse in Asus Nexus device,but when i run it the device is listed as below:-

```
?????????????  no permission
```

and does allow to select ok.  I have also tried to set the rule for the device as mentioned in the developer.android tutorial..but still no change..I am using ubuntu..can anyone pls help me to fix it out?

Comment: Try this way, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11839511/603744

Comment: If you've always had this problem, try what @AndroSelva suggests in the comment. If it used to work ok, but now it shows up like this, try disabling and re-enabling debug on your Android device.

Comment: Thank you so much..Problem is solved :-)

Answer (score 1):

USB debugging is not enabled in your android device.

Set it in your device go to

Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging

USB debugging = True

Comment: It was set to usb debugging mode.